# Add a column in a Pandas dataframe and input a certain name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am working with a dataset using Pandas (Python/Jupyter notebook).

I want to search one column in dataset imported and if some of the text appears add a new column with particular details and input a particular name eg

I want to search the following dataset so if Tom appears in the set add column named Team and input Team 1 at the end of the row where it finds Tom
If Bill appears in the set add Team 2 under the new column

**Name**,                         **Age**,                  **Sport**,
Tom Smith,                         29,                          Rugby,
Billy John,                        21,                          Rugby,
Henry Clips,                       25,                          Rugby,

Answer (score 2):

Jupyter notebook is just an interface which allows you to combine python lines with markup for something that is easy to read. As for your problem, it might help to be a little descriptive.

What are you using to create the table? Is it pandas library? If it is you could do something like

```
df["Team"]=np.nan # add a new column called team
df["Team"][df["Name"]=="Tom"]=1 #where Tom make team 1
df["Team"][df["Name"]=="Bill"]=2 and so on
```

Comment: This would be better posted  as a comment until OP clarifies the request. In its current state, the question is impossible to answer with any certainty.